# Database Directory storage is full need to change link it to new Partition

Tags: centos, mysql

My mysql Database Directory size is full. So I want to change it to another partition where there is large amount of space. The database version am using is MySQL 5.7.23 and OS is CentOS 7.

After searching internet i got 2 solutions. First one as follows:

Firstly,I created a Systemlink pointing to the new drive. Then I tried to start mysql, it fails everytime when I try to start. On removing systemlink it will start.

The error am getting is

```
[Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-08-21T10:08:04.839330Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 
13 in a file operation.
2018-08-21T10:08:04.839349Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does 
not have the access rights to the directory.
2018-08-21T10:08:04.839360Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: os_file_readdir_next_file() 
returned -1 in directory ./, crash recovery may have failed for some .ibd 
files!
2018-08-21T10:08:04.839385Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted 
with error Generic error
2018-08-21T10:08:05.440529Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned 
error.
2018-08-21T10:08:05.440597Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a 
STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-08-21T10:08:05.440610Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2018-08-21T10:08:05.440617Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-08-21T10:08:05.440665Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-08-21T10:08:05.440770Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2018-08-21T10:08:05.441349Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Secondly, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a- 
mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04 I followed this url and after that when tried to start mysql keep on getting this error Cant connect to localhost (111) (Error: 2003). This time nothing is showing in mysqld.log file

Answer (score 0):

The message says that "mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory". So you should check the rights of the new directory you have created. The directory should usually be owned by user mysql, group mysql. You should also check the all parents of the new directory have at least execute permissions for mysql.

Comment: chmod -R 777 /folder

Comment: Maybe AppArmor / SELinux is blocking access to the directory.

Comment: chown mysql:mysql /folder

Comment: SElinux is disabled